# HermiT does not seem to show inferenced DataProperties ?

Tags: ontology, protege, pellet, hermit, reasoner

I created an ontology using Protege, and added SWRL rules, using Hermit Reasoner, everything was fine, but it does not show inferenced DataProperties.

I tried using Pellet, it was able to inference DataProperties, but, all my SWRL rules i created does not work anymore.

Is this a Bug from Hermit ? is there a solution ? 
Best Regards.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: i also faced the same problem :/ sa7bi il zouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that DataProperty inferencing  is not supported By Hermit, so i have to change to Pellet, you might find this problem when you change from Hermit to Pellet : things like differentFrom(?a , ?b) in swrl rules become swrlb:notEqual(?a, ?b)  and etc...